# Always get "Error validating verification code." when requesting access_token

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

Well, I have done all my best to try to solve this problem, but, still, it's too annoying.

I decided to use OAuth with server-side authentication. So, I have followed Facebook documentation, and I have done the following step.

1. Create a link which redirect people to log in Facebook by `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={APP_ID}&redirect_uri=http://abc.com/nextStep.php`
2. In nextStep.php, redirect people to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code={CODE GENERATED BY FACEBOOK}&client_id={APP_ID}&redirect_uri=http://abc.com/thirdStep.php&client_secret={APP_SECRET}`

The problem exists when proceeding to step 2. The page shows that:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating verification code.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

I have googled for lots of time. Some people suggests to add a trailing slash in the redirect_uri, but it doesn't work. What should I do? And how can I get the user information after getting the access_token? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First, I’d say you’re missing the `state` parameter in your first URL … you have to make up a value that the docs describe as SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING – some unique id/hash/whatever, that no one from the outside would be able to guess. (Yes, that parameter is *optional* – but you *should* use it anyway, because as the docs say it helps prevent CSRF and is therefore an *important* security measure. If you don’t know what CSRF means, please look it up.)

And second, in your step two, you should **not** *redirect* the user’s client to that address, but make a *server side* call to that endpoint instead. You are putting your app secret into this URL (that’s not the mistake, you have to) – so it would be easy for the user to get it if you called that URL in his browser …!

I’d suggest you start with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ again, reading it carefully from the top – you can hardly go wrong if you really follow the instructions given there one-by-one …